# Instagram API: Get All User Media API and Store to File

Tags: php, json, pagination, instagram

I know the way to get all user media in instagram api with pagination. And we must request again with pagination url provided to get next photos.

I just wonder if i can save all of json api response include with next photos in pagination to one flat file for caching. The purpose is i can call all photos value from one file only, e.g: cache.json.

Is there a way to realize that in PHP Code if possible? Like using file_get and file_put function. Any help is appreciated so much :)

Comment: lets see your code, what have you tried?

Comment: you can get the complete list of images as one big file if you add the parameter `&count=-1` to the end of the request.

Comment: No, with params &count=-1 you'll lost many values like caption value to null, comment, and other.
I didn't try it. I just have an idea that may possible to realize it with store all to one file and if any updates with the instagram account just trigger the code to fetch and store all again.

Comment: Look at my code below. Maybe you can fix it.

Comment: New code updated. Look below

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code, but need a tweak to fix it. Im using this wrapper https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

```
require 'instagram.class.php'; 
$cache = './cache.json'; 

$instagram = new Instagram($accessToken); 
$instagram->setAccessToken($accessToken); 
$response = $instagram->getUserMedia($userID,$settings['count']); 

do {

if($response){ 
file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($response)); //Save as json 
} 
} while ($response = $instagram->pagination($response));

echo 'finish';
```

With this code i getting the last pagination only. It seems the code overwrite the cache.json file, not adding.
Maybe you can suggest me how to fix it become adding, not overwriting.

**-- Edit --**

My code now working but not perfect, maybe you can try and fix it.

```
<?php 
include('conf.php'); 
require 'instagram.class.php'; 

$cache = './cache_coba.json'; 

$instagram = new Instagram($accessToken); 
$instagram->setAccessToken($accessToken); 
$response = $instagram->getUserMedia($userID,$settings['count']); 

while ($response = $instagram->pagination($response)) {
if($response){ 
$opn = file_get_contents($cache); 
$opn .= json_encode($response);
file_put_contents($cache, $opn);
} 
} 

echo 'finish';
?>
```